# Hide and Showing loaded data (show more function)

Tags: jquery, html

I have json data from my webserver using ajax. This data are video urls and information.

How can I only show the 1st four videos. Then hide other videos (when they are already loaded to html). Then adding show more button function to show the other four video on the list.

I display the video list like this:

```
 $.each(data[2], function(i, row) {
  var video_link = row.video_youtube_link;
  var video_img = row.video_youtube_thumbnail;
  var video_title = row.video_youtube_title;
  var video_description = row.video_youtube_description;
  var video_duration = row.video_youtube_duration;
  var video_published = row.video_youtube_date_published;

  var str = "<div class='video-list-wrapper'>";
   str += "<div class='video-wrap'>";
   str += "<div class='left-video-info'><a href=#null onclick=document.getElementById('video').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_link+"'><img src="+ video_img +" width='100%' height='auto'></a><span class='video-duration'>"+parseDuration(video_duration)+"</span></div>";                 
   str += "<div class='right-video-info'>";
   str += "<div class='video-title'>"+video_title+"</div>";
   str += "<div class='video-date'>"+ video_published +" ago</div>";
   str += "</div>";//right-info 
   str += "</div>";//video-wrap
   str += '</div>';
  $('#video-list').append(str); 
});
```

Ok I tried to make a function from scrap. And it is working now..

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var numvideo = $('.video-list-wrapper').length;
    x=3;
    $('.video-list-wrapper:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= numvideo) ? x+5 : numvideo;
        $('.video-list-wrapper:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
});
```

Here is the sample showing the populated data:
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/xkevin/h2hegehv/5/)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you link is not valid,so we can't help you ,better post the javascript code here

Comment: wait, I will update it.

Comment: where is the code where you attempted to create the load more function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make an answer while searching.. This is my final ouput. Thanks for those who make an effort in helping me out.

```
 var numvideo = $('.video-list-wrapper').length;

  addvideo = 4;
  $('.video-list-wrapper:lt(' + addvideo + ')').show();
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    addvideo = (addvideo + 4 <= numvideo) ? addvideo + 4 : numvideo;
    $('.video-list-wrapper:lt(' + addvideo + ')').show();
  });
  $('#showLess').click(function() {
    addvideo = (addvideo - 4 < 0) ? 4 : addvideo - 4;
    $('.video-list-wrapper').not(':lt(' + addvideo + ')').hide();
  });
```

Working code here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkevin/h2hegehv/)

Answer (score 1):

wrap 4 videos in a div, hide the first using `hide()`
on a button click hide the previous and show the next

```
$.each(data[2], function(i, row) {
  var video_link = row.video_youtube_link;
  var video_img = row.video_youtube_thumbnail;
  var video_title = row.video_youtube_title;
  var video_description = row.video_youtube_description;
  var video_duration = row.video_youtube_duration;
  var video_published = row.video_youtube_date_published;
   str = '';
   if(i%4 == 0) { 
    str += "<div class='video-4-wrap'>";
   }
   str += "<div class='video-list-wrapper'>";
   str += "<div class='video-wrap'>";
   str += "<div class='left-video-info'><a href=#null onclick=document.getElementById('video').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_link+"'><img src="+ video_img +" width='100%' height='auto'></a><span class='video-duration'>"+parseDuration(video_duration)+"</span></div>";                 
   str += "<div class='right-video-info'>";
   str += "<div class='video-title'>"+video_title+"</div>";
   str += "<div class='video-date'>"+ video_published +" ago</div>";
   str += "</div>";//right-info 
   str += "</div>";//video-wrap
   str += '</div>';
   if(i%4 == 0) { 
    str += "</div>";//video-4-wrap
   }
  $('#video-list').append(str); 
}); 

$('.video-4-wrap').not(':first').hide();
$('button').click(function(){
var viz = $('.video-4-wrap:visibile');
viz.prev().hide();
viz.next().show();

});
```